# O que é um objeto retornado entre parênteses?

Tags: java

```
    }

    return (carro);
}
```

Ele tem algum comportamento diferente que do objeto sem parênteses? Fiquei na dúvida, aparentemente o código funciona normalmente.

Comment: @mgibsonbr por que não responde? Só esse trecho do seu comentário já é melhor do que qualquer resposta que eu poderia dar.

Comment: Quem votou para fechar: Ele só está querendo saber se `return foo;`  é diferente de `return (foo); `, se o uso (ou não) de parênteses influência em algo. :)

Answer (score 5):

Em Java, um único elemento entre parênteses é idêntico ao mesmo elemento sem nenhum parêntese. Apenas quando há dois ou mais elementos é que o parêntese importa - seja melhorando a legibilidade (ver [resposta do MarcusVinicius](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68831/215)) seja afetando a precedência (ordem de execução) dos operadores (ver [resposta do Maicon](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68839/215)). Do contrário, o comportamento será idêntico, pois ao transformar o código-fonte em *bytecodes* o mesmo código de montagem será gerado com ou sem os parênteses:

SemParenteses.java

```
public int teste() {
    int carro = 42;
    return carro;
}
```

SemParenteses.class

```
public int teste();
  Code:
     0: bipush        42
     2: istore_1      
     3: iload_1       
     4: ireturn
```

ComParenteses.java

```
public int teste() {
    int carro = 42;
    return (carro);
}
```

ComParenteses.class

```
public int teste();
  Code:
     0: bipush        42
     2: istore_1      
     3: iload_1       
     4: ireturn
```

Outras linguagens poderiam ter um comportamento diferente (em Lisp o parêntese criaria uma nova lista, em Python o parêntese vazio, com dois ou mais elementos ou com uma vírgula após `carro` criariam uma [tupla](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enupla), etc), mas em Java não há nenhum significado especial do mesmo à parte de estabelecer a ordem de avaliação das expressões envolvidas.

Answer (score 1):

> O que é um objeto retornado entre parenteses?

A resposta a sua pergunta é simples: o próprio objeto!

Não existe diferença alguma no valor ou no comportamento de um objeto colocado entre parênteses dessa maneira.

Há alguns casos que a legibilidade pode ser melhorada ao colocar-se entre parênteses. Considere o seguinte caso:

```
return umaCondicao && umValor > 0 || outroValor == 1;
```

Pode ficar mais claro se escrito:

```
return (umaCondicao && umValor > 0) || (outroValor == 1);
```

Porém o valor retornado é o mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Os parenteses em java serve para executar expressões separadamente. Por exemplo.

Isso:

```
return 5 + 5 * 2;
```

E diferente disso:

```
return (5 + 5) * 2;
```

No primeiro caso vai retorna 15 no segundo vai retorna 20.

> Ele tem algum comportamento diferente que do objeto sem parênteses?

Não, mais pode haver uma pequena queda de performance.

Por que o java vai tentar executar uma expressão dentro dos parenteses.